# Creating columns based on total number of columns in a data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have to import an excel document every month containing data from agencies by month in a wide format. The data looks like this:

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
|Agency   | Jan-18 | Feb-18 | Mar-18 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Agency1 |  1,996 |  2,042 |  2,045 |
| Agency2 |    609 |    701 |    611 |
| Agency3 |  1,119 |  1,176 |  1,158 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I would like to have 13 columns in my data frame; one for the facility cariable plus 12 months. In this case I would like to create 9 more columns. Something like "if ncol(df)< 13 (accounting for the first variable) then create 13-ncol(df) columns". I need to do this because I want to rename all the columns at once and because I don't want to do it manually depending on the number of columns of different datasets (based on the month).

```
colnames(df)[1:13] <- c("Fac", "m.Jan", "m.Feb", "m.Mar", "m.Apr", "m.May", "m.Jun",
                         "m.Jul", "m.Aug","m.Sep", "m.Oct", "m.Nov", "m.Dec")
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible, quick solution would be something like the following.
After specifying the working directory, you read the data

```
data <- read.csv("filename.csv")
```

then you use an *if* statement to check whether your dataset has less than 13 columns

```
if (ncol(data) < 13) {
new_df <- as.data.frame( matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(data), ncol = 13 - ncol(data)) )
df <- cbind(data, new_df)
}
```

Basically here I'm creating a matrix full of *NA*'s which has the same number of rows as 
*data* and the remaining number of columns such that the final dataframe *df* has 13 columns.

At the end, you rename the variable names as you wish:

```
colnames(df) <- c("Fac", "m.Jan", "m.Feb", "m.Mar", "m.Apr", "m.May", "m.Jun",
                    "m.Jul", "m.Aug","m.Sep", "m.Oct", "m.Nov", "m.Dec")
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Ric, Thank you so much for your help! This is going to help  me a lot! I am fairly new to R (I used to work with Stata). I need to explore more your codes to understand the commands you are using. But the first part just creates a data frame with Nulls values based on the columns of my original data. And the second part just merge the datasets. Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what my code is doing. If you need more help just ask!